# Linux boots when I click "Windows 7" in boot manager

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, usb, multi-boot

I've been trying to dual boot, which has pretty much been successful. I have Linux installed on an external Hard Drive. In the boot manager when I click on Windows 7:

- (with the hard drive plugged in), it boots Linux Mint.
- (**without** the hard drive plugged it), it boots Windows 7.

I even set up the boot manager with **Easy BCD**, and when I click on "Linux Mint", I get this error:

[image: Screenshot]

My current theory is that it has something to do with USB 3.0 and 2.0

When I'm in Windows, it really only recognizes the hard drive (well in Easy BCD anyway) when I'm in a USB 3.0 port. Although when I actually boot (like I said I click Windows 7 and Linux loads) that only works when it is in USB 2.0.

So basically I need it to be in USB 3.0 for Windows to recognize it, but USB 2.0 to make it boot.

**Any ideas/solutions?**